# Function to extract delimited fields

Tags: r, dataframe, csv, extract

I need a function that helps extracting fields from a user-specified format.

The text is table-like, but the delimiters vary.

Example:

```r
text="1 ; a) first line - good
0.1 ; b)
1 ; aa)  description - (ok)"
```

Notice that

- not all rows are complete.
- delimiters can be in text strings too ( ")" is the second delimiter but is also in the string "(ok)"

I need to construct a function called fun.extract. It should be called like this:

```r
fun.extract(text,format="value;symbol)text-note")
```

The result should be

```r
data.frame(value=c(1,.1,1),
symbol=c("a","b","aa"),
text=c("first line",NA,"description"),
note=c("good",NA,"(ok)")
)
```

The idea is it extracts text until it reaches the first delimiter, then until the next etc until end of line. I am aware I will need to limit what characters can be in variable names/delimiters for the function to be able to separate what is what. Delimiters are everything that is not alphanumeric.

I can obviously put together the data.frame in the end but I am struggling to put together the regular expressions to extract the contents. I hope I can stick with base R functions like sub not to pull in dependencies for my package just for this.

Comment: Are delimiters always a single character?

Comment: @Nick, that would be OK

Comment: [This](https://regex101.com/r/2F4TXL/1) is probably a good starting point

Comment: `read.csv2(text=gsub("(?m)(^[^(\n]+)[)]|-", "\\1;", text,perl = TRUE), header = FALSE, na.strings = "", col.names = c('value', 'symbol', 'text', 'note'))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
read.csv2(text = gsub("(?m)(^[^(\n]+)[)]|-", "\\1;", text,perl = TRUE), 
          header = FALSE, na.strings = "", 
          col.names = c('value', 'symbol', 'text', 'note'))

  value symbol           text  note
1    1       a    first line   good
2  0.1       b           <NA>  <NA>
3    1      aa   description   (ok)
```

Comment: Thank you Onyambu! This works in this particular case. But how do I generate such an expression based on the user-specified format? What if for instance 
`format="value%symbol)text%note - note2"`? I need to generate the regex based on what the user wants to do.

Comment: @JohnDoe consider having different examples in your question